# pip3 install tesserocr gives error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.6

I am trying to install tesserocr package for python3.6 on Ubuntu. When I run `pip3 install tesserocr`, 
I get this error:

```
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for tesserocr ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-cmhownuf/tesserocr/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpg1f69eahpip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
  Supporting tesseract v4.0.0-beta.1
  Configs from pkg-config: {'include_dirs': ['/usr/include'], 'libraries': ['lept', 'tesseract'], 'cython_compile_time_env': {'TESSERACT_VERSION': 1024}}
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'tesserocr' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.6-EKG1lX/python3.6-3.6.5=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c tesserocr.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/tesserocr.o
  cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
  tesserocr.cpp: In function ‘tesseract::TessResultRenderer* __pyx_f_9tesserocr_13PyTessBaseAPI__get_renderer(__pyx_obj_9tesserocr_PyTessBaseAPI*, __pyx_t_9tesseract_cchar_t*)’:
  tesserocr.cpp:21180:106: error: no matching function for call to ‘tesseract::TessPDFRenderer::TessPDFRenderer(__pyx_t_9tesseract_cchar_t*&, const char*)’
         __pyx_t_3 = new tesseract::TessPDFRenderer(__pyx_v_outputbase, __pyx_v_self->_baseapi.GetDatapath());
                                                                                                            ^
  In file included from tesserocr.cpp:625:0:
  /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:190:3: note: candidate: tesseract::TessPDFRenderer::TessPDFRenderer(const char*, const char*, bool)
     TessPDFRenderer(const char* outputbase, const char* datadir, bool textonly);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:190:3: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
  /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:186:16: note: candidate: tesseract::TessPDFRenderer::TessPDFRenderer(const tesseract::TessPDFRenderer&)
   class TESS_API TessPDFRenderer : public TessResultRenderer {
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:186:16: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
  /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:186:16: note: candidate: tesseract::TessPDFRenderer::TessPDFRenderer(tesseract::TessPDFRenderer&&)
  /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:186:16: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
  tesserocr.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* PyInit_tesserocr()’:
  tesserocr.cpp:34594:81: error: ‘OEM_CUBE_ONLY’ is not a member of ‘tesseract’
     __pyx_t_10 = __Pyx_PyInt_From_enum__tesseract_3a__3a_OcrEngineMode(tesseract::OEM_CUBE_ONLY); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_10)) __PYX_ERR(0, 84, __pyx_L1_error)
                                                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
  tesserocr.cpp:34594:81: note: suggested alternative: ‘OEM_LSTM_ONLY’
     __pyx_t_10 = __Pyx_PyInt_From_enum__tesseract_3a__3a_OcrEngineMode(tesseract::OEM_CUBE_ONLY); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_10)) __PYX_ERR(0, 84, __pyx_L1_error)
                                                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                                   OEM_LSTM_ONLY
  tesserocr.cpp:34607:81: error: ‘OEM_TESSERACT_CUBE_COMBINED’ is not a member of ‘tesseract’
     __pyx_t_10 = __Pyx_PyInt_From_enum__tesseract_3a__3a_OcrEngineMode(tesseract::OEM_TESSERACT_CUBE_COMBINED); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_10)) __PYX_ERR(0, 85, __pyx_L1_error)
                                                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  tesserocr.cpp:34607:81: note: suggested alternative: ‘OEM_TESSERACT_LSTM_COMBINED’
     __pyx_t_10 = __Pyx_PyInt_From_enum__tesseract_3a__3a_OcrEngineMode(tesseract::OEM_TESSERACT_CUBE_COMBINED); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_10)) __PYX_ERR(0, 85, __pyx_L1_error)
                                                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                                   OEM_TESSERACT_LSTM_COMBINED
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for tesserocr
  Running setup.py clean for tesserocr
Failed to build tesserocr
Installing collected packages: tesserocr
  Running setup.py install for tesserocr ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-cmhownuf/tesserocr/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-uewp6mk4-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=:
    Supporting tesseract v4.0.0-beta.1
    Configs from pkg-config: {'include_dirs': ['/usr/include'], 'libraries': ['tesseract', 'lept'], 'cython_compile_time_env': {'TESSERACT_VERSION': 1024}}
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'tesserocr' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.6-EKG1lX/python3.6-3.6.5=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c tesserocr.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/tesserocr.o
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    tesserocr.cpp: In function ‘tesseract::TessResultRenderer* __pyx_f_9tesserocr_13PyTessBaseAPI__get_renderer(__pyx_obj_9tesserocr_PyTessBaseAPI*, __pyx_t_9tesseract_cchar_t*)’:
    tesserocr.cpp:21180:106: error: no matching function for call to ‘tesseract::TessPDFRenderer::TessPDFRenderer(__pyx_t_9tesseract_cchar_t*&, const char*)’
           __pyx_t_3 = new tesseract::TessPDFRenderer(__pyx_v_outputbase, __pyx_v_self->_baseapi.GetDatapath());
                                                                                                              ^
    In file included from tesserocr.cpp:625:0:
    /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:190:3: note: candidate: tesseract::TessPDFRenderer::TessPDFRenderer(const char*, const char*, bool)
       TessPDFRenderer(const char* outputbase, const char* datadir, bool textonly);
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:190:3: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
    /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:186:16: note: candidate: tesseract::TessPDFRenderer::TessPDFRenderer(const tesseract::TessPDFRenderer&)
     class TESS_API TessPDFRenderer : public TessResultRenderer {
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:186:16: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
    /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:186:16: note: candidate: tesseract::TessPDFRenderer::TessPDFRenderer(tesseract::TessPDFRenderer&&)
    /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:186:16: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
    tesserocr.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* PyInit_tesserocr()’:
    tesserocr.cpp:34594:81: error: ‘OEM_CUBE_ONLY’ is not a member of ‘tesseract’
       __pyx_t_10 = __Pyx_PyInt_From_enum__tesseract_3a__3a_OcrEngineMode(tesseract::OEM_CUBE_ONLY); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_10)) __PYX_ERR(0, 84, __pyx_L1_error)
                                                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    tesserocr.cpp:34594:81: note: suggested alternative: ‘OEM_LSTM_ONLY’
       __pyx_t_10 = __Pyx_PyInt_From_enum__tesseract_3a__3a_OcrEngineMode(tesseract::OEM_CUBE_ONLY); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_10)) __PYX_ERR(0, 84, __pyx_L1_error)
                                                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                                     OEM_LSTM_ONLY
    tesserocr.cpp:34607:81: error: ‘OEM_TESSERACT_CUBE_COMBINED’ is not a member of ‘tesseract’
       __pyx_t_10 = __Pyx_PyInt_From_enum__tesseract_3a__3a_OcrEngineMode(tesseract::OEM_TESSERACT_CUBE_COMBINED); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_10)) __PYX_ERR(0, 85, __pyx_L1_error)
                                                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    tesserocr.cpp:34607:81: note: suggested alternative: ‘OEM_TESSERACT_LSTM_COMBINED’
       __pyx_t_10 = __Pyx_PyInt_From_enum__tesseract_3a__3a_OcrEngineMode(tesseract::OEM_TESSERACT_CUBE_COMBINED); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_10)) __PYX_ERR(0, 85, __pyx_L1_error)
                                                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                                     OEM_TESSERACT_LSTM_COMBINED
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-cmhownuf/tesserocr/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-uewp6mk4-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-cmhownuf/tesserocr/
```

Comment: Could you please also include the version of pip? pip3 --version

Comment: I get a similar error when trying to install it on macOS. Seems to be a problem with the package.

Comment: Might be a good idea to open an issue on their github page: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/

I get tesserocr.cpp:596:34: fatal error: leptonica/allheaders.h: No such file or directory ... tried with pip8

Comment: My pip3 version is 9.0.1.

Comment: Actually, looking at their [wiki on GitHub](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki) I wonder if it's really meant to be installed via `pip`. It seems to be available via `apt` in the Ubuntu package repo: `sudo apt install tesseract-ocr`. Maybe you should better use that instead? @HenryXiao

Comment: Actually, I have already installed tesseract-ocr. It's a software which should be run in terminal, but I want to installed the package for python to use it.@anothernode

Comment: My pip3 version is 9.0.1.@Mircea

Comment: Maybe you can run sudo apt-get install python-dev. You lost some head file.@Mircea

Comment: There's also a `libtesseract-dev` package in the Ubuntu repos. Could that be what you are looking for?

Comment: I have installed libtesseract-dev.@anothernode

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone, I have solved it. I download tesserocr source file from git and ran:

```
henry@PC:~/tesserocr$ pip3 install .
Processing /home/henry/tesserocr
Installing collected packages: tesserocr
  Running setup.py install for tesserocr ... done
Successfully installed tesserocr-2.2.2
```

It took a lot time, but it finally worked. It seemes that the pip source of tesserocr doesn't match the latest tesseract-ocr, it should be installed manually.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link to [tesserocr](https://anaconda.org/mcs07/tesserocr)

Instead of pip, install it with conda. This will solve your problem.

```
conda install -c mcs07 tesserocr
```

Answer (score 0):

same error in Mac, because python3 is 3.6.3 upgrade to 3.7.2 then install successful

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install on Windows 10, using pip, by installing locally from the latest Wheel file (check https://github.com/simonflueckiger/tesserocr-windows_build/releases).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).